# RegisterClass. Различие между глобальными и локальными классами

Tags: windows, winapi

Читаю [статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#application-global-classes). Как я понял, кастомные классы регистрируются только в рамках текущего процесса. Но в чем отличие глобальных и локальных классов?

- **Application Global Classes**

  > An application global class is a window class registered by an executable or DLL that is available to all other modules in the process. For example, your .dll can call the RegisterClassEx function to register a window class that defines a custom control as an application global class so that a process that loads the .dll can create instances of the custom control.

  > Глобальный класс приложения - это класс окна, зарегистрированный исполняемым файлом или библиотекой DLL, который доступен всем остальным модулям в процессе. Например, ваша .dll может вызывать функцию RegisterClassEx, чтобы зарегистрировать класс окна, который определяет настраиваемый элемент управления как глобальный класс приложения, чтобы процесс, загружающий .dll, мог создавать экземпляры настраиваемого элемента управления.
- **Application Local Classes**

  > An application local class is any window class that an executable or .dll registers for its exclusive use. Although you can register any number of local classes, it is typical to register only one. This window class supports the window procedure of the application's main window.

  > Локальный класс приложения - это любой класс окна, который исполняемый файл или DLL регистрирует для своего исключительного использования. Хотя вы можете зарегистрировать любое количество локальных классов, обычно регистрируется только один. Этот класс окна поддерживает оконную процедуру главного окна приложения.

Или локальные классы видны только в текущем модуле и две dll в одном процессе могут зарегистрировать класс с одним именем и это будут разные классы? Более того, другие модули вообще не видят чужих классов? Т.е. `CreateWindow`, вызываемый в основном приложении с именем класса, для которого `RegisterClass` был вызван в dll без флага `CS_GLOBALCLASS` вернет `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS`?

И еще вопрос:

> The system destroys a local class when the module that registered it closes. An application can also use the UnregisterClass function to remove a local class and free the storage associated with it.

> Система уничтожает локальный класс, когда модуль, который его зарегистрировал, закрывается. Приложение также может использовать функцию UnregisterClass для удаления локального класса и освобождения связанного с ним хранилища.

Я правильно понимаю, что при выгрузке dll локальный класс, который был зарегистрирован в этой dll, уничтожается?

Но [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterclassa) написано вот так

> No window classes registered by a DLL are unregistered when the .dll is unloaded.

> Ни один оконный класс, зарегистрированный библиотекой DLL, не будет отменен при выгрузке .dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ [здесь](https://www.transl-gunsmoker.ru/2010/04/hinstance-createwindow-registerclass.html)

> Одного имени оконного класса ещё не достаточно для уникальной идентификации класса окна. Каждый процесс имеет свой собственный набор оконных классов, поэтому каждая запись в списке оконных классов состоит из описателя экземпляра (instance handle) и имени класса

> Когда наступает время создать окно, каждый модуль передаёт свой описатель для создания окна, а менеджер окон использует его комбинацию с именем класса для поиска нужного оконного класса

> Однако в описанном выше правиле есть одно исключение. Если вы укажете флаг CS_GLOBALCLASS при регистрации класса, то менеджер окон будет игнорировать описатель модуля во время поиска этого класса.

Т.е. для локальных классов нужно в `CreateWindow` передавать тот `hInstance`, который был указан в структуре `WNDCLASS` при регистрации класса. Для глобальных классов `hInstance` игнорируется